Не могу подключиться к L2TP-серверу из-под Linux (Network manager)! unrecognized option '/dev/pts/2'
И так, есть у меня удалённый хост c сервером L2TP/IPSec и два компа (дома и на работе). Первый на Windows 10, второй на Antix Linux. На виндовском компе не возникло абсолютно никаких проблем - создал на нём VPN-подключение, ввёл PSK, логин, пароль - подключился, тоннель работает. Вот лог xl2tpd на сервере для этого компа:
xl2tpd[8902]: Connection established to 5.139.144.60, 1701.  Local: 61450, Remote: 131 (ref=0/0).  LNS session is 'default'
xl2tpd[8902]: start_pppd: I'm running:
xl2tpd[8902]: "/usr/sbin/pppd"
xl2tpd[8902]: "/dev/pts/1"
xl2tpd[8902]: "passive"
xl2tpd[8902]: "nodetach"
xl2tpd[8902]: "192.168.194.1:192.168.194.11"
xl2tpd[8902]: "refuse-pap"
xl2tpd[8902]: "auth"
xl2tpd[8902]: "require-chap"
xl2tpd[8902]: "name"
xl2tpd[8902]: "srvl2tp"
xl2tpd[8902]: "file"
xl2tpd[8902]: "/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd"
xl2tpd[8902]: Call established with 5.139.144.60, PID: 8904, Local: 52083, Remote: 135, Serial: 4

А вот на рабочем компе, с линуксом, возникли большие проблемы! В Network Manager сделал всё то же самое - создал VPN-подключение, ввёл PSK, логин с паролем уже другой учётки, и... фейл! Соединение поднимается, и тут же падает. Что бы я ни делал, какие бы настройки не менял - результат один, сервер выдаёт следующий лог:
xl2tpd[8902]: Connection established to 27.78.113.110, 59491.  Local: 32635, Remote: 47333 (ref=0/0).  LNS session is 'default'
xl2tpd[8902]: start_pppd: I'm running:
xl2tpd[8902]: "/usr/sbin/pppd"
xl2tpd[8902]: "/dev/pts/2"
xl2tpd[8902]: "passive"
xl2tpd[8902]: "nodetach"
xl2tpd[8902]: "192.168.194.1:192.168.194.12"
xl2tpd[8902]: "refuse-pap"
xl2tpd[8902]: "auth"
xl2tpd[8902]: "require-chap"
xl2tpd[8902]: "name"
xl2tpd[8902]: "srvl2tp"
xl2tpd[8902]: "file"
xl2tpd[8902]: "/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd"
xl2tpd[8902]: Call established with 27.78.113.110, PID: 8924, Local: 28613, Remote: 58967, Serial: 1
xl2tpd[8902]: control_finish: Connection closed to 27.78.113.110, serial 1 ()
xl2tpd[8902]: Terminating pppd: sending TERM signal to pid 8924
/usr/sbin/pppd: unrecognized option '/dev/pts/2'
pppd version 2.4.9
Usage: /usr/sbin/pppd [ options ], where options are:
        <device>        Communicate over the named device
        <speed>         Set the baud rate to <speed>
        <loc>:<rem>     Set the local and/or remote interface IP
                        addresses.  Either one may be omitted.
        asyncmap <n>    Set the desired async map to hex <n>
        auth            Require authentication from peer
        connect <p>     Invoke shell command <p> to set up the serial line
        crtscts         Use hardware RTS/CTS flow control
        defaultroute    Add default route through interface
        file <f>        Take options from file <f>
        modem           Use modem control lines
        mru <n>         Set MRU value to <n> for negotiation
See pppd(8) for more options.
xl2tpd[8902]: control_finish: Connection closed to 27.78.113.110, port 59491 (Server closing), Local: 32635, Remote: 47333

Всё то же самое, что для виндовского компа, но теперь появляется ошибка: /usr/sbin/pppd: unrecognized option '/dev/pts/2', и pppd закрывается вместе с соединением!
В чём тут дело, почему, как исправить?? Проблема не гуглится совершенно! Помогите решить её!
Привожу файл /etc/xl2tpd.conf на сервере:
[global]
port = 1701
auth file = /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
access control = no
 
[lns default]
exclusive = no
ip range = 192.168.194.11-192.168.194.250
hidden bit = no
local ip = 192.168.194.1
length bit = yes
require chap = yes
refuse pap = yes
require authentication = yes
name = srvl2tp
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
flow bit = yes

Файл /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd:
noccp
auth
mtu 1410
mru 1410
nodefaultroute
noproxyarp
silent
asyncmap 0
hide-password
require-mschap-v2
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
logfile /var/log/xl2tpd.log
debug

Я совершенно сейчас не представляю, в каком направлении копать. На винде работает. Есть ещё роутер mikrotik, на нём тоже соединение работает. А на линухе, как обычно, очередная >|<опа на ровном месте!...

Есть сильное подозрение, что ошибка в pppd - не причина, а следствие закрытия соединения...

За одну бессонную ночь и полдня разобрался в проблеме. На линуксовом компьютере демон pppd требовал библиотеки libcrypt.so.1.1 и libssl.so.1.1, которые в дистрибутив забыли положить. В репозитариях, понятно, их тоже не оказалось. Скачал с первого-попавшегося форума соответствующий deb-пакет для Ubuntu, распаковал эти библиотеки в /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, и всё прекрасно заработало (хоть и для Ubuntu, но под Antix подошло).
В общем, причина проблемы - очередное головотяпство разработчиков дистрибутива, у которых частая неразбериха с установленными пакетами в порядке вещей, к сожалению.
P.S. Написал сам себе ответ, мне не жалко)) Может кому-то ещё поможет, кто вдруг столкнётся с такой же проблемой...
